# How is an icon stored inside an executable?

Tags: windows, icons

I am not able to find any information on this. There are tools that exist to extract icons from .exe files, but my question is how are they stored in the first place?

Comment: Why in blue blazes did this get moved to SU?  This is clearly a programming question, the only access to this information is programmatic - what a stupid move.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft documents this quite extensively

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx